# This currency coverter in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, oop

1. problem: the cout is always strange numbers or the else cout or the cout that say "useless conversion"
   . I've tried also using integers and strings instead of letters for the currencies but doesn't work anyway
2. I've done in Object oriented programming for necessity

```
        
        #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;
        
    /*Object oriented programming*/
    
        class Convertitore{
            public: 
                char vEntrata, vUscita;
                double qEntrata;
                Convertitore();
                Convertitore(char vEntrata, char vUscita, double qEntrata);
                double Calcolo();
        };
        
        Convertitore::Convertitore(){
            vEntrata = 'a';
            vUscita = 'a';
            qEntrata = 0;
        }
        
        Convertitore::Convertitore(char vEntrata, char vUscita, double qEntrata){
            vEntrata = vEntrata;
            vUscita = vUscita;
            qEntrata = qEntrata;
        }
        
        double Convertitore::Calcolo(){
            if(vEntrata == 'e' && vUscita == 'e'){
                cout << "Useless conversion";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'e' && vUscita == 'd'){
                cout << qEntrata << "€ equal to " << qEntrata*1.22 << "$";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'e' && vUscita == 'l'){
                cout << qEntrata << "€ equal to " << qEntrata*1936 << "£";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'd' && vUscita == 'e'){
                cout << qEntrata << "$ equal to " << qEntrata/1.22 << "€";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'd' && vUscita == 'd'){
                cout << "Useless conversion";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'd' && vUscita == 'l'){
                cout << qEntrata << "$ equal to " << qEntrata*1510.29 << "£";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'l' && vUscita == 'e'){
                cout << qEntrata << "£ equal to " << qEntrata/1936.27 << "€";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'l' && vUscita == 'd'){
                cout << qEntrata << "£ equal to " << qEntrata/1510.29 << "$";
            }
            else if(vEntrata == 'l' && vUscita == 'l'){
                cout << "Useless conversion";
            }
            else{
                cout << "wrong inputs";
            }   
        }
        
        
        int main(){
            char vEntrata, vUscita;
            double qEntrata;
            cout << "Scegli la valuta da convertire: digita e per euro, d per dollar, l per italian lira: "; cin >> 
            vEntrata;
            cout << "Scegli la valuta in cui convertire: digita e per euro, d per dollar, l per italian lira: "; cin 
            >> vUscita;
            cout << "digitare la quantità di " << vEntrata << " da convertire: "; cin >> qEntrata;
            Convertitore Valuta = Convertitore(vEntrata, vUscita, qEntrata);
            cout << Valuta.Calcolo();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't cout/cin on the same line it's hard to read because it's unexpected. Also, please show that you have stepped through this code in a debugger and can see which if statement is acting in a manner you do not expect or understand.

Comment: Also, please fix compiler warnings/errors - you cout the return value of calcolo, which claims to return a double but doesn't return anything. The compiler is complaining about this for a reason!

Comment: thanks. I'll do these things

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor

```
Convertitore::Convertitore(char vEntrata, char vUscita, double qEntrata){
    vEntrata = vEntrata;
    vUscita = vUscita;
    qEntrata = qEntrata;
}
```

You are assigning local variables to themselves.

You can use the member initializer list instead:

```
Convertitore::Convertitore(char vEntrata, char vUscita, double qEntrata)
    : vEntrata(vEntrata),
      vUscita(vUscita),
      qEntrata(qEntrata)
{}
```

---

Secondly your function `double Convertitore::Calcolo()` promises to return a `double`, but doesn't return anything.
Because of this the line

```
cout << Valuta.Calcolo();
```

causes undefined behaviour and most likely will print garbage data.
It seems like `Calcolo` isn't designed to return something, but print the result directly. If that's what you want, change the return type to `void`:

```
void Convertitore::Calcolo()
```

and don't attempt to print the (now non-existent) return value.

Comment: Maybe you'd care to point out (and correct) the major error in the `Calcolo` function, too?